# nuxt where to import global modules from node_modules

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I want to import a node module globally:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

Where/how should I implement the import?

Answer (score 1):

open your manifest.json file in public folder 
it mentions starturl . you can go to that file and add your import. as it is the starting point of your app , it works globally .[image: see here]